# Toolbar overflow menu click animation overlaps

Tags: android

I have the following style definitions for my application:

styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textcolorsecundary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primaryColor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar" />
```

When i now click on the overflow menu a small circular animation appears but its incomplete. half of the animation is hiding under the title label:

An example you can see here:

[image]

The red area shows the smal touch animation which appears when you tap on the overflow menu to expand it. As you can see it is incomplete just half of the circle is visible.

Its the same when i tap on an action item of the overflow menu:

[image]

Just the red area is animated. It seems like the animation is hiding behind the labels of the actionbar and menu items.

How can i make the full animation visible?